# regex for first occurring char semicolon or empty space or single quote

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I have been trying to make a regex expression which can match all the below strings.  I was able to make a regex for first two, but unable to do for the next 2.  The regex should be such that the matching is performed only until the end of error message.

```
RAISERROR 20001 @errmsg;
RAISERROR 20001 @errmsg
RAISERROR 20001 @'ajhsgdjh jahsgdjahsgdjg'
RAISERROR 20001 @'ajhsgdjh jahsgdjahsgdjg';
```

Below is the test link:

https://regex101.com/r/ntywvP/3

```
((?i)raiserror)\s*\d{5,6}\s*([^;|\s*]*)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `'.'`.  Are there any strings you _don't_ want to match?  Should something be considered "generalizable" in the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace `([^;|\s*]*)` by `(@[^;\r\n]*)`. You could try the following regex.

```
(?i)raiserror\s*\d{5,6}\s*(@[^;\r\n]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ntywvP/8)

Comment: Thank you,this worked for me ... only change was that I grouped it for easy replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
\bRAISERROR \d+ @(?:'[\w ]+'|[\w ]+);?
```

### Demo

I deal with the optional single quoted message by using an alternation which allows either for this, or for a message sans single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can match all between the single quotes or match only non whitespace chars. If you don't need the capturing group around `((?i)raiserror)` you can omit it.

```
(?i)raiserror\s*\d{5,6}\s*@(?:'[^'\r\n]*'|\S+);?
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` case insensitive modifier
- `raiserror\s*\d{5,6}\s*` Match raiserror and 5-6 digits between optional whitespace chars
- `@` Match the @ char
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `'[^'\r\n]*'` Match any char except `'` between an opening and closing `'`
  - `|` Or
  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `);?` Close group and match optional `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TpU53d/1)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is https://regex101.com/r/ntywvP/4

```regex
^((?i)raiserror)\s*\d{5,6}\s*(.+?)(;|\s*)$
```

Capturing the string beginning with `@` is done via matching a s few characters as possible with `(.+?)`. This allows specifying possible characters after the wildcard before the end of the line.

`^` matches line start
`$` matches line end

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you can use either:

```
'.'
```

This matches everything in the world with at least one character, so it will match all four of your strings.

Or to match the four strings exactly:

```
'RAISERROR 20001 @errmsg|RAISERROR 20001 @errmsg|RAISERROR 20001 @'ajhsgdjh jahsgdjahsgdjg|RAISERROR 20001 @'ajhsgdjh jahsgdjahsgdjg'
```

You haven't specified the rules for what strings you want to match and what strings you don't.  Any other solutions require guessing on what you *mean* but haven't explained.